# update/add multiple properties while keeping old

Tags: neo4j

I have a node labeled **test** and properties including **name='abc'** in neo4j db. I need update this node with dynamic set of properties( these properties are coming as a json from third party system) while ***keeping older properties*** as it is using neo4j Rest API.
I have followed https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/ article and came up with following request body.

```
{
   "statements" : [ {
      "statement" : "match (n:test {name:'abc'}) set n={properties} return n",
      "parameters": {
          "properties": {"title":"t1"}
      }
   } ]
}
```

But this erase all older properties leaving only one property which is **title** . How can I use transactional API to add/modify properties while keeping existing ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `+=` instead of `=` if you want to keep existing properties.

That is:

```
{
   "statements" : [ {
      "statement" : "match (n:test {name:'abc'}) set n+={properties} return n",
      "parameters": {
          "properties": {"title":"t1"}
      }
   } ]
}
```